# Identify this 8 pin device - top markings 317S4 3482A

Tags: identification, components

I am trying to fix my Sony soundbar. On the main board, I found a burned-out device (transistor?). After searching for the numbers from the top of it, I can't find any information about it.

[image: 8 pin device]

Answer (score 1):

That is not a transistor.

It's a EUP3482A synchronous buck regulator.

Which is not obvious from the picture as there is no surrounding components visible.

Comment: Yes but what is obvious is that the regulator is burned out due to an input overvoltage >>35V (pin 2)